# Why must I implement a function for an interface in vb.net which apparently doesn't need to be implemented in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I am working through converting the code in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173618/MVVM-sharp-Episode-1) CodeProject article from C# to VB.net.  Most of this has gone well, but this last bit is confusing me and I'm hoping that someone can explain why.
It centres arounding converting some code that implements an interface.

Here is the c# interface

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public interface ICustomerController : IController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Return a collection of Customer information to be displayed in a list 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A collection of Customers</returns>
        CustomerSelectionViewData GetCustomerSelectionViewData(string stateFilter);
        /// <summary>
        /// Do whatever needs to be done when a Customer is selected (i.e. edit it)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="customerId"></param>
        void CustomerSelectedForEdit(CustomerListItemViewData data, BaseViewModel daddy);
        /// <summary>
        /// Edit this customer Id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="customerId"></param>
        void EditCustomer(int customerId, BaseViewModel daddy);
        /// <summary>
        /// Update Customer data in the repository
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        void UpdateCustomer(CustomerEditViewData data);
    }
}
```

Followed by the files that implements it.

```
using ViewModels;
using Views;
namespace Controllers
{
    public partial class CustomerController : ICustomerController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The ShowView methods are private. A ViewModel may request some action to take place, 
        /// but the Controller will decide whether this action will result in some view being 
        /// shown.
        /// e.g. clicking a 'Search' button on a form may result in a Command being sent from the
        /// View (via binding) to the ViewModel; the Command handler then asks the Controller to
        /// Search for whatever.
        /// The controller may (for example) use a service to return a collection of objects. if there
        /// is only a single object, then it may return a single object rather than popping up a search
        /// view only to have the User be presented with a single action from which to select.
        /// </summary>

        #region Show Views

        private void ShowViewCustomerSelection()
        {
            CustomerSelectionView v = GetCustomerSelectionView();
            v.ShowInWindow(false, "MVVM# Customer Selection");
        }
        #endregion

        #region Get Views
        private CustomerSelectionView GetCustomerSelectionView(BaseViewModel daddy = null)
        {
            CustomerSelectionView v = new CustomerSelectionView();
            CustomerSelectionViewModel vm = new CustomerSelectionViewModel(this, v);

            if (daddy != null)
            {
                daddy.ChildViewModels.Add(vm);
            }

            return v;
        }


        private BaseView GetCustomerEditView(int customerId, BaseViewModel daddy)
        {
            CustomerEditView v = new CustomerEditView();
            CustomerEditViewModel vm = new CustomerEditViewModel(this, v);

            vm.ViewData = GetCustomerEditViewData(customerId);

            if (daddy != null)
            {
                daddy.ChildViewModels.Add(vm);
            }

            return v;
        }


        #endregion



    }
}
```

and

```
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Messengers;
using Model;
using Service;
using ViewModels;


namespace Controllers
{
    public partial class CustomerController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get a collection of Customers and return an Observable collection of CustomerListItemViewData
        /// for display in a list.
        /// You could bypass this conversion if you wanted to present a list of Customers by binding directly to 
        /// the Customer object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public CustomerSelectionViewData GetCustomerSelectionViewData(string stateFilter)
        {
            CustomerSelectionViewData vd = new CustomerSelectionViewData();
            vd.Customers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerListItemViewData>();

            foreach (var customer in CustomerService.GetListOfCustomers(stateFilter))
            {
                vd.Customers.Add(new CustomerListItemViewData()
                {
                    CustomerId = (int)customer.Id,
                    CustomerName = customer.Name,
                    State = customer.State
                });
            }
            return vd;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the Edit View Data for the Customer Id specified
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="customerId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public CustomerEditViewData GetCustomerEditViewData(int customerId)
        {
            var customer = CustomerService.GetCustomer(customerId);
            return new CustomerEditViewData()
            {
                CustomerId = customer.Id,
                Name = customer.Name,
                Address = customer.Address,
                Suburb = customer.Suburb,
                PostCode = customer.PostCode,
                State = customer.State,
                Phone = customer.Phone,
                Email = customer.Email
            };
        }

        public void UpdateCustomer(CustomerEditViewData data)
        {
            Customer item = new Customer()
            {
                Id = data.CustomerId,
                Address = data.Address,
                Name = data.Name,
                Suburb = data.Suburb,
                PostCode = data.PostCode,
                Email = data.Email,
                Phone = data.Phone,
                State = data.State

            };
            CustomerService.UpdateCustomer(item);
            Messenger.NotifyColleagues(MessageTypes.MSG_CUSTOMER_SAVED, data);
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
    using Messengers;
using Service;
using ViewModels;
using Views;

namespace Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The controller 'is' the application.
    /// Everything is controlled by this :
    /// it instantiates Views and ViewModels
    /// it retrieves and stores customers via services
    /// 
    /// But it does all this only in response to requests
    /// made by the ViewModels.
    /// 
    /// e.g. a ViewModel may request a list of customers
    /// e.g. a ViewModel may want to save changes to a customer
    /// 
    /// set up as a partial class for convenience
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CustomerController : BaseController, ICustomerController
    {
        private static ICustomerService CustomerService;

        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Private constructor - we must pass a service to the constructor
        /// </summary>
        private CustomerController()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The controller needs a reference to the service layer to enable it to make service calls
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="customerService"></param>
        public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService)
        {
            CustomerService = customerService;
        }
        #endregion


        #region Public Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Main entry point of the Controller.
        /// Called once (from App.xaml.cs) this will initialise the application
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            ShowViewCustomerSelection();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Edit the customer with the Id passed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="customerId">Id of the customer to be edited</param>
        /// <param name="daddy">The 'parent' ViewModel who will own the ViewModel that controls the Customer Edit</param>
        public void EditCustomer(int customerId, BaseViewModel daddy = null)
        {
            BaseView view = GetCustomerEditView(customerId, daddy);
            view.ShowInWindow(true, "Edit Customer");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A Customer has been selected to be edited
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The CustomerListItemViewData of the selected customer</param>
        /// <param name="daddy">The parent ViewModel</param>
        public void CustomerSelectedForEdit(CustomerListItemViewData data, BaseViewModel daddy = null)
        {
            // Check in case we get a null sent to us
            if (data != null && data.CustomerId != null)
            {
                NotificationResult result = Messenger.NotifyColleagues(MessageTypes.MSG_CUSTOMER_SELECTED_FOR_EDIT, data);
                if (result == NotificationResult.MessageNotRegistered || result == NotificationResult.MessageRegisteredNotHandled)
                {
                    // Nothing was out there that handled our message, so we'll do it ourselves!
                    EditCustomer((int)data.CustomerId, daddy);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

and here are the corresponding VB conversions;

Interface

```
Namespace ViewModels
Public Interface ICustomerController
    Inherits IController

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Return a collection of Customer information to be displayed in a list 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>A collection of Customers</returns>
    Function GetCustomerSelectionViewData(ByVal stateFilter As String) As CustomerSelectionViewData
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Do whatever needs to be done when a Customer is selected (i.e. edit it)
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="customerId"></param>
    Sub CustomerSelectedForEdit(ByVal data As CustomerListItemViewData, ByVal daddy As BaseViewModel)
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Edit this customer Id
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="customerId"></param>
    Sub EditCustomer(ByVal customerId As Integer, ByVal daddy As BaseViewModel)
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Update Customer data in the repository
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="data"></param>
    Sub UpdateCustomer(ByVal data As CustomerEditViewData)
End Interface
End Namespace
```

Code file implementing interface

```
 Imports ViewModels
Imports Views
Namespace Controllers
    Partial Public Class CustomerController
        Implements ICustomerController

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The ShowView methods are private. A ViewModel may request some action to take place, 
        ''' but the Controller will decide whether this action will result in some view being 
        ''' shown.
        ''' e.g. clicking a 'Search' button on a form may result in a Command being sent from the
        ''' View (via binding) to the ViewModel; the Command handler then asks the Controller to
        ''' Search for whatever.
        ''' The controller may (for example) use a service to return a collection of objects. if there
        ''' is only a single object, then it may return a single object rather than popping up a search
        ''' view only to have the User be presented with a single action from which to select.
        ''' </summary>

        #Region "Show Views"

        Private Sub ShowViewCustomerSelection()
            Dim v As CustomerSelectionView = GetCustomerSelectionView()
            v.ShowInWindow(False, "MVVM# Customer Selection")
        End Sub
        #End Region

        #Region "Get Views"
        Private Function GetCustomerSelectionView(Optional ByVal daddy As BaseViewModel = Nothing) As CustomerSelectionView
            Dim v As New CustomerSelectionView()
            Dim vm As New CustomerSelectionViewModel(Me, v)

            If daddy IsNot Nothing Then
                daddy.ChildViewModels.Add(vm)
            End If

            Return v
        End Function


        Private Function GetCustomerEditView(ByVal customerId As Integer, ByVal daddy As BaseViewModel) As BaseView
            Dim v As New CustomerEditView()
            Dim vm As New CustomerEditViewModel(Me, v)

            vm.ViewData = GetCustomerEditViewData(customerId)

            If daddy IsNot Nothing Then
                daddy.ChildViewModels.Add(vm)
            End If

            Return v
        End Function


        #End Region



    End Class
    End Namespace
```

To my eye these look to be pretty faithful conversions and the c# code definitely compiles and runs in the solution I downloaded from code project.

The VB file that implements the interface tells me that I should be implementing the functions; GetCustomerSelectionViewData, CustomerSelectedForEdit,EditCustomer and UpdateCustomer.

I can see that they are in the interface, and yes I accept that logic dictates that they should be implemented, but surely this would be the case in C# as well and yet that compiles perfectly and goes on to run perfectly.

I'd welcome thoughts from those who know more than me and suggestions as to how I should approach this aspect of the conversion.

EDIT

here are the two other parts of the partial class, where as you can see the relevant functions are implemented.

```
    Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Messengers
Imports Model
Imports Service
Imports ViewModels


Namespace Controllers
    Partial Public Class CustomerController
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Get a collection of Customers and return an Observable collection of CustomerListItemViewData
        ''' for display in a list.
        ''' You could bypass this conversion if you wanted to present a list of Customers by binding directly to 
        ''' the Customer object.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <returns></returns>
        Public Function GetCustomerSelectionViewData(ByVal stateFilter As String) As CustomerSelectionViewData
            Dim vd As New CustomerSelectionViewData()
            vd.Customers = New ObservableCollection(Of CustomerListItemViewData)()

            For Each customer In CustomerService.GetListOfCustomers(stateFilter)
                vd.Customers.Add(New CustomerListItemViewData() With {.CustomerId = CInt(customer.Id), .CustomerName = customer.Name, .State = customer.State})
            Next customer
            Return vd
        End Function

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Get the Edit View Data for the Customer Id specified
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="customerId"></param>
        ''' <returns></returns>
        Public Function GetCustomerEditViewData(ByVal customerId As Integer) As CustomerEditViewData
            Dim customer = CustomerService.GetCustomer(customerId)
            Return New CustomerEditViewData() With {.CustomerId = customer.Id, .Name = customer.Name, .Address = customer.Address, .Suburb = customer.Suburb, .PostCode = customer.PostCode, .State = customer.State, .Phone = customer.Phone, .Email = customer.Email}
        End Function

        Public Sub UpdateCustomer(ByVal data As CustomerEditViewData)
            Dim item As New Customer() With {.Id = data.CustomerId, .Address = data.Address, .Name = data.Name, .Suburb = data.Suburb, .PostCode = data.PostCode, .Email = data.Email, .Phone = data.Phone, .State = data.State}
            CustomerService.UpdateCustomer(item)
            Messenger.NotifyColleagues(MessageTypes.MSG_CUSTOMER_SAVED, data)
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

and

```
 Imports Messengers
Imports Service
Imports ViewModels
Imports Views

Namespace Controllers
    ''' <summary>
    ''' The controller 'is' the application.
    ''' Everything is controlled by this :
    ''' it instantiates Views and ViewModels
    ''' it retrieves and stores customers via services
    ''' 
    ''' But it does all this only in response to requests
    ''' made by the ViewModels.
    ''' 
    ''' e.g. a ViewModel may request a list of customers
    ''' e.g. a ViewModel may want to save changes to a customer
    ''' 
    ''' set up as a partial class for convenience
    ''' </summary>
    Partial Public Class CustomerController
        Inherits BaseController
        Implements ICustomerController

        Private Shared CustomerService As ICustomerService

        #Region "Constructors"
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Private constructor - we must pass a service to the constructor
        ''' </summary>
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The controller needs a reference to the service layer to enable it to make service calls
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="customerService"></param>
        Public Sub New(ByVal customerService As ICustomerService)
            CustomerController.CustomerService = customerService
        End Sub
        #End Region


        #Region "Public Methods"
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Main entry point of the Controller.
        ''' Called once (from App.xaml.cs) this will initialise the application
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub Start()
            ShowViewCustomerSelection()
        End Sub
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Edit the customer with the Id passed
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="customerId">Id of the customer to be edited</param>
        ''' <param name="daddy">The 'parent' ViewModel who will own the ViewModel that controls the Customer Edit</param>
        Public Sub EditCustomer(ByVal customerId As Integer, Optional ByVal daddy As BaseViewModel = Nothing)
            Dim view As BaseView = GetCustomerEditView(customerId, daddy)
            view.ShowInWindow(True, "Edit Customer")
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' A Customer has been selected to be edited
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="data">The CustomerListItemViewData of the selected customer</param>
        ''' <param name="daddy">The parent ViewModel</param>
        Public Sub CustomerSelectedForEdit(ByVal data As CustomerListItemViewData, Optional ByVal daddy As BaseViewModel = Nothing)
            ' Check in case we get a null sent to us
            If data IsNot Nothing AndAlso data.CustomerId IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim result As NotificationResult = Messenger.NotifyColleagues(MessageTypes.MSG_CUSTOMER_SELECTED_FOR_EDIT, data)
                If result = NotificationResult.MessageNotRegistered OrElse result = NotificationResult.MessageRegisteredNotHandled Then
                    ' Nothing was out there that handled our message, so we'll do it ourselves!
                    EditCustomer(CInt(data.CustomerId), daddy)
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
        #End Region

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the 'Implements' clauses on the methods implementing the interface methods.
I've just reproduced the interesting parts of the conversion below with the appropriate 'Implements' clauses - also in VB you can't use an optional parameter to implement a non-optional parameter:

```
Partial Public Class CustomerController
    Implements ICustomerController

    Public Function GetCustomerSelectionViewData(ByVal stateFilter As String) As CustomerSelectionViewData Implements ICustomerController.GetCustomerSelectionViewData
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Sub UpdateCustomer(ByVal data As CustomerEditViewData) Implements ICustomerController.UpdateCustomer
    End Sub
End Class

Partial Public Class CustomerController
    Inherits BaseController
    Implements ICustomerController

    Public Sub EditCustomer(ByVal customerId As Integer, ByVal daddy As BaseViewModel) Implements ICustomerController.EditCustomer
    End Sub

    Public Sub CustomerSelectedForEdit(ByVal data As CustomerListItemViewData, ByVal daddy As BaseViewModel) Implements ICustomerController.CustomerSelectedForEdit
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Many thanks Dave, one of the perils of using converters when you're not overly familiar with the source language.

Answer (score 3):

Just look at this line of code:

```
public partial class CustomerController : ICustomerController
```

and note - it's [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).

This means somewhere else in the project there are some other parts of this class, and implementation of all `ICustomerController` interface methods **should** be in that parts - and may not present in part of code you've shown.

There is no way in C# to declare class as implementing some interface and not to implement that interface methods in any part of class.

Answer (score 3):

The `CustomerController` is a `partial class` so that methods implemented in another parts of class (CustomerController_DataRetrieval.cs, CustomerController_ViewManagement.cs).

Answer (score 2):

That is definitely not possible. When I compile the source you provided I get four errors. Exactly the four errors you would expect:

> 'ViewModels.Controllers.CustomerController' does not implement interface member 'ViewModels.ICustomerController.UpdateCustomer(ConsoleApplication8.CustomerEditViewData)'
>   'ViewModels.Controllers.CustomerController' does not implement interface member 'ViewModels.ICustomerController.EditCustomer(int, ConsoleApplication8.BaseViewModel)'
>   'ViewModels.Controllers.CustomerController' does not implement interface member 'ViewModels.ICustomerController.CustomerSelectedForEdit(ConsoleApplication8.CustomerListItemViewData, ConsoleApplication8.BaseViewModel)'
>   'ViewModels.Controllers.CustomerController' does not implement interface member 'ViewModels.ICustomerController.GetCustomerSelectionViewData(string)'

**Note that your class is `partial`.** Are you sure you didn't define that methods somewhere else? It simply can't be not implemented.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for your comment.  Yes it's a partial class and yes those methods are implemented in the other parts of the partial class which I have added to my original question as an edit.  To my eyes everything seems in order, but it may be a case of missing the wood for the trees.

Comment: added below the other two c# extracts.

Comment: Essentially why is the vb conversion reporting errors when as far as I can see it's a pretty faithful conversion of the c# which doesn't.  I have closed and restarted visual studio a couple of times to try and ensure that there were no potential caching issues but still it stubbornly tells me to implement functions which I know to be implemented.

Comment: The four errors that I mentioned in the main body of the question, failing to implements the methods GetCustomerSelectionViewData, CustomerSelectedForEdit, EditCustomer and UpdateCustomer.